# Paypal IPN - store data on database, update and delete

Tags: php, mysql, database, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using [this example](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration) to store in the database the info coming from PayPal, my problem is that the database create two records for the same sale, one with the status of 'Pending' and one with the status 'Completed', both for the same sale.

How can I change this part of the code so if there is a sale with the same 'txn_id' I just update the 'payment_status' row OR delete the whole thing before update it with the new info. Note that there is two rows that will be different, 'payment_status' and 'createdtime' .

```
function updatePayments($data){ 
    global $link;
    if(is_array($data)){                
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, item_name, receiver_email, payer_email, custom, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
                '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_amount']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_status']."' ,
                '".$data['item_name']."' ,
                '".$data['receiver_email']."' ,
                '".$data['payer_email']."' ,
                '".$data['custom']."' ,
                '".$data['itemid']."' ,
                '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
                )", $link);
    return mysql_insert_id($link);
    }
}
```

Database structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payments` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txnid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `payment_amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `payment_status` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `receiver_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `payer_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `custom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `itemid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `createdtime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `txn_id` (if one doesn't exist already) and then use either [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replace.html) in place of your existing [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html).

---

**UPDATE**

In your case, to add the unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE payments ADD UNIQUE INDEX (txnid);
```

Then, append to the end of your `INSERT` statement:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE payment_status = '".$data['payment_status']"'
```

If you want to delete the existing record and replace it with your new one, just change the word `INSERT` to `REPLACE` instead.

Comment: I just update the question with the database structure, can you post an example (I'm new to databases).

Comment: The orange box says that I can accept your answer in one minute, so I will wait until that. THANKS A LOT !!!